# return list of columns with distinct values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data like the example below.  I would like to return a list of all columns that have different values, like the example output below.

I can think of how to do this if I just had two records in my data, transpose and create a new column that just compares the two columns, but I’m not sure how to do this for more than two records of data.  Any tips are greatly appreciated.

Print df:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3
A       c       d
A       f       d
A       c       e
```

Desired output:

```
[Col2, Col3]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### `filter`

```
list(filter(lambda c: df[c].nunique() > 1, df))

['Col2', 'Col3']
```

Answer (score 4):

Using `nunique`

```
df.nunique().gt(1).loc[lambda x : x].index
Out[97]: Index(['Col2', 'Col3'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Efficient than what I had. `s=df.T.apply(lambda x: x.nunique(), axis=1)`
then, `list(s[s!=1].index)`

Comment: @piRSquared Wow I'm dumb, I posted an answer before I saw your comment. And now I'm out of delete votes (so I can't delete my answer), and I'm out of upvotes so I can't upvote your answers either... well I can try to fix the second problem.

Comment: `world[0]` problems!

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ I have  vote left , let me give to your answer :-)

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ You need a delete vote for your own post?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I already deleted 5 of my posts today, so I can't remove any more.

Answer (score 2):

Similarly, index on `df.columns`:

```
df.columns[df.nunique().gt(1)]
```

```
Index(['Col2', 'Col3'], dtype='object')
```